# Is it legitimate to use Rcpp to speed up replacing elements of lists and vectors in iterative algorithm?

Tags: c++, r, bigdata, subset, rcpp

## Context

I have been working on iterative algorithm lately, where each iteration `n` depends on the iteration `n-1`. During each iteration most of the computation time is taken by sub-setting and/or replacing elements of vectors, lists or data.tables (N > 10^6).

I recently came across Rcpp and playing a little bit with it I discovered that replacing element `k` of vectors or lists can be sped up by two or three orders of magnitudes (few benchmark tests below).

However, when using the Rcpp subsetting code within a for and a while loop, R seems to become unstable and the session aborts at random points with no hint of what went wrong.

## Question

**My question:** *is this use of Rcpp legitimate or it can leads to problems I am not aware of?*

### Example

Below is the Rcpp code I am using and a few benchmarks. Overall, the algorithm should call the replacing functions ~5.5 billion times and subset functions ~50 billion times.

Note that replacing elements of lists and double vectors is faster using Rcpp, *while for integer vectors base R solutions are preferred* (*benchmark 1*); data table is a good option to replace elements but if you have to subset repeatedly to access its elements the vector approach is much faster (*benchmark 2*).

**Functions:**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]

void assign_list(List x, int k, NumericVector new_element){
  x[k-1] = new_element;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void assign_dbl(NumericVector x, int k, double y){
  x[k-1] = y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void assign_int(IntegerVector x, int k, int y){
  x[k-1] = y;
}
```

**Benchmarks:**

***Inputs***

```
set.seed(747474)

int <- 1:10^7
dou <- rnorm(10^7, 1000, 300)
l   <- lapply(sample(5:20, 10^7,  replace = T), rnorm, mean = 1000, sd = 300)
dt  <- data.table(int = int, dou = dou, l = l)

i <- 999999
z <- 2222
k <- 30000
s <- 552877
```

***1)***

```
Unit: nanoseconds
                                     expr      min       lq        mean      median        uq       max neval
                             int[i] <- -1L     488     2439  36938108.9      4146.0  15651119 799720107    30
                             dou[i] <- -1      732     3170  19101960.4   6609193.5  16187500 212369197    30
                             l[i]   <- -1      489     3902 159442538.1 186035314.5 227131872 618326686    30
                               assign_int 19853910 22028692  81055363.5  24665494.0  39352345 872241539    30
                               assign_dbl     1220     5852     48023.2      8534.5     13167   1158828    30
                              assign_list     1464     6828     52866.9     10850.5     13411   1243430    30
 dt[k, ':=' (int = -1, dou = -1, l = -1)]   206020   340116    481850.0    425326.5    529312   1414341    30
```

***2)***

```
microbenchmark(times = 30L,

               "subset vector + list" = {int[s]; dou[s]; l[s]},
               "subset datatable"     = {dt[s, int]; dt[s, dou]; dt[s, l]})

Unit: nanoseconds
                 expr    min     lq       mean   median     uq     max neval
 subset vector + list    488    488   1715.533   1585.5   2926    4389    30
     subset datatable 563688 574417 719304.467 600138.0 875765 1308040    30
```

Comment: Switch from `[]` to `()` to enable bounds checking. Any "instability" is likely an "out of bounds" error triggering an undefined behavior (UB) causing the crash. Make sure you are account for the fact that _C++_ indices start at 0 and **not** 1.

Comment: @coatless, thanks. Once i change to  `x(k-1) = new_element` if there is an "out of bounds" error what will it happen?

Comment: The code will error and you'll get one of the spiffy new Rcpp error messages stating the extent was surpassed.

Answer (score 5):

This is very dangerous, because of the side effect shown here, where `x` and `y` are changed even though you only  pass `x` into the Rcpp function

```
> x <- y <- 1:10
> assign_int(x, 1, 2)
> y
 [1]  2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

It does not seem to be faster; for these functions

```
f0 <- function(x) {
    for (i in seq_along(x))
        x[i] = -i
}

f1 <- function(x) {
    for (i in seq_along(x))
        assign_int(x, i, -i)
}
```

I have

```
> int <- 1:10^5
> microbenchmark(f0(int), f1(int), times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 f0(int)  14.78777  14.80264  15.05683  15.03138  15.17678  15.48556     5
 f1(int) 659.67346 669.00095 672.93343 670.48917 676.16930 689.33429     5
```

In your benchmark, `int[i] <- 1`, '`1`' is a numeric (double) value, so you are coercing to a double vector (check out `class(int)` after the assignment), triggering a complete copy. Use `int[i] <- 1L` to force the right-hand side to be an integer.

```
> int0 <- int1 <- 1:10^7
> microbenchmark(int0[1] <- 1, int1[1] <- 1L)
Unit: microseconds
          expr   min    lq      mean median     uq       max neval
  int0[1] <- 1 1.047 1.102 1770.9911  1.143 1.2650 176960.52   100
 int1[1] <- 1L 1.105 1.176  339.4264  1.213 1.2655  33815.97   100
> class(int0)
[1] "numeric"
> class(int1)
[1] "integer"
```

Updating just a single element as benchmark is expensive in base R because it triggers a copy of the vector on each assignment; in `f0()` the copy occurs just once. On the first iteration, R makes a copy because it knows that the vector of integer values is referenced by at least two symbols (the argument to the function `int`, and the symbol used in the function `x`) so it makes a copy of the memory and assigns it to `x` inside the function. It does this to avoid the side-effect seen in your Rcpp code (i.e., to avoid modifying `int`). The next time through the loop R recognizes that only a single symbol references the vector, so does the replacement without making a copy.

Note that

```
> int <- 1:10^5
> f1(int)
> head(int)
[1] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
```

illustrates the subtle way that the side-effects of your Rcpp code can have unexpected outcomes.

Also, there are several ways of slowing down iterative loops, e.g.,

```
f2 <- function(x) {
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        x[i] = -i
        y <- x
    }
}

f3 <- function(x) {
    result <- integer()
    for (i in seq_along(x))
        result <- c(result, -i)
}
```

with

```
> int <- 1:10^3
> microbenchmark(f0(int), f2(int), f3(int), times = 1)
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f0(int)  150.507  150.507  150.507  150.507  150.507  150.507     1
 f2(int)  667.201  667.201  667.201  667.201  667.201  667.201     1
 f3(int) 4379.005 4379.005 4379.005 4379.005 4379.005 4379.005     1
```

`f2()` causes R to make a copy of `x` each time through the loop (to avoid the side-effect of modifying `y`). `f3()` copies a vector of length 0, 1, 2, 3, ... n - 1 (where `n = length(x)`) on successive iterations, leading to `n * (n - 1) / 2` elements copied, and an algorithm that scales as the square of the length of `x`.

The general principle applies to other types as well, including lists with

```
f0l <- function(x) {
    for (i in seq_along(x))
        x[[i]] <- i
    x
}

f1l <- function(x) {
    for (i in seq_along(x))
        assign_list(x, i, i)
}
```

leading to

```
> set.seed(123)
> l0   <- lapply(sample(5:20, 10^6,  replace = T), rnorm, mean = 1000, sd = 300)
> set.seed(123)
> l1   <- lapply(sample(5:20, 10^6,  replace = T), rnorm, mean = 1000, sd = 300)
> microbenchmark(f0l(l0), f1l(l1), times=1)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 f0l(l0)  239.9865  239.9865  239.9865  239.9865  239.9865  239.9865     1
 f1l(l1) 6767.9172 6767.9172 6767.9172 6767.9172 6767.9172 6767.9172     1
```

Comment: Dear Martin thank you very much for your reply. Indeed the assign_int is not faster than base R (in fact I am not using it in my actual script - I posted it for completeness). I did actually use -1L in the benchmark although the label was misleading (I have corrected it now). **The side effect you are talking about is exactly what I was looking for** and, especially in the list case but also for double vectors, makes the code MUCH faster because to my understanding no copy is made. The whole point is that I have to access and update single elements at each iteration.

Comment: I hope we're on the same page; `f0()` updates single elements each iteration and is faster than the Rcpp solution.

Comment: Indeed the assign_int is not faster than base R (in fact I am not using it in my actual script - I posted it for completeness). For lists and double vectors Rcpp does speed up a lot my code, and since my intent is to modify `dou` and `l` the side effect you describe is actually the only intent those functions have.

Comment: Again it is straight-forward to write code (`f0()`, now also `f0l()`) where R does not make excessive copies, see for instance the addition at the end of my response. Also, the side effect is NOT a good thing; you might think you have an understanding of when it will be important, but you will almost certainly introduce hard-to-understand behavior into your code.

Comment: To clarify, the "side effect" I mention is the unintended modification, in the first lines of my response, of `y`, rather than your intended modification of `x` only.

Comment: So your point is that if I include the script in a function environment it will be much faster, am I right? However function about f1l() one would rather rewrite it entirely in Rcpp/C++ (I did and it and `f0l` and `f1l` have similar benchmarks). (I was aware of the side effect - modifying `y` together with `x`)

Comment: It is not being in a function environment, but whether R (and you) can reason about how many symbols reference a given vector. In `f0()`, only `x` is referencing the vector where R stores it's representation.

Comment: Yes, Rcpp seems to have a cost associated with making the call to Rcpp, and you pay this cost `n` times if called from in an R loop, but only once if the loop is also written in C++. But then, you  end up exactly where you started and have had to write error-prone C++ code (note your initial implementation documented in the comments with @coatless) for limited performance gain and for a very bad side effect.

Comment: Probably your code is currently written as `f2()` or `f3()`, and the R-based solution is to avoid those idioms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179397/discussion-between-gerald-t-and-martin-morgan).